# Is there a way to save AVDepthData for video for IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, avassetwriter, avdepthdata

I'm trying to make an IOS app that saves AVDepthData for a video as mp4. I tried using AVAssetWriter but it didn't work (Problem similar to - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/685883). My intention is to save both RGB & DepthMap and later extend it to SceneDepth from ARKit.